# Where to place global variables in MVVM (Caliburn micro)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm refactoring a program done in WinForms to WPF and I'm using Caliburn.Micro as a framework to implement the MVVM pattern.

In the old program, I use a `StatisHelper` class to allow different static variables like the theme, the language, the username or the rights of access, etc ..

I know that it could be insecure because these variables are public, but I doubt that my end users know how to access these values...

Anyway, I would like to know the best practice in MVVM to save global values *(in concrete, I'm using Caliburn.Micro framework)* that can be accessed for all the view-models.

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108568/where-should-constants-label-text-etc-come-in-wpf-mvvm-application?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a singleton class (frowned upon by some). Note that the constructor is `private`, so nothing else can create an instance. Use the `Instance` property to access it. The `Instance` property in this example will only construct the singleton object the first time it's accessed.

To use it, simply do something like `var foo = Globals.Instance.SomeProperty`.

Note that this has nothing to do with WPF or MVVM, and could have been used in WinForms as well.

```
public class Globals {
    private Globals _Instance;
    public Globals Instance {
        get {
            if (_Instance == null)
                _Instance = new Globals();
            return _Instance;
        }
    }

    private Globals() {
    }

    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Globals.Instance.SomeProperty cannot be called.  Instance needs to be defined with "static". eg. private static Globals _instance; and public static Globals Instance{ get{...} }

Comment: Please add static to the code like @alex mentioned. Like this the Singleton's members are not accessible!

Answer (score 3):

I use a custom `StateManager` class that implements the `Singleton` pattern so that there is only one of these instances in the application:

```
public class StateManager : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static StateManager instance = new StateManager();

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialises a new empty StateManager object.
    /// </summary>
    public StateManager() { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the single available instance of the application StateManager object.
    /// </summary>
    public StateManager Instance
    {
        get { return instance; }
    }

    ...
}
```

This is then referenced in my base view model, so that all of my view models have access to it:

```
public StateManager StateManager
{
    get { return stateManager.Instance; }
}
```

Furthermore, because it is referenced in my view model classes, I can also `Bind` to the values in XAML:

```
<Window Title="{Binding StateManager.WindowTitle, Mode=OneWay}" ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

Well my answer is a combination of ideas from the @Steve and @Sheridan and the link in the comment.

First of all, I have to say separate the data from the code.

As for the data, I would use those *Resx* files to store all those kinds of resources, whether they are binary resources like simple audio files, images, localizable strings, etc .., because this makes it easy to swap them at run-time.

As for the code, I would use a collection like `IConfigurationProvider` like this:

```
public interface IConfigurationProvider {

    GetResourceByName<T>(string key); // T is the type of the requested resource

    // THIS IS A SIMPLIFIED VERSION, YOU CAN HAVE MORE METHODS
    // ACCORDING TO YOUR NEEDS 

}
```

The implementation of this interface could use the *Resx* files to store and retrieve resources, then you can inject those resources into the different classes that need it.

This haves some advantages like:

- Better testability
- Can use different media to store the resource data without changing the interface
- Swap the implementation at run-time, you can use DI now.
- More clear where is the data coming from

Comment: I'm sorry @Sniffer, I am new in coding (I'm trying to do all my best), so, could you detail it me a little bit more, please? Sorry for the inconveniences. Thank you.

Comment: @OscarMateu You need to be more specific, what is it that you feel confused about ? It's subject worth an article on its own.

Comment: Hi @Sniffer, where I have to use this interface? In the MainWindowViewModel? I have a one active conductor with multiple screens, each one with its viewmodel.

Comment: @OscarMateu You can use it wherever to you need to pull information from the resources. Usually in my applications I have a configuration screen where you can set application options and I use it there.